# JavaFX Label word wrap with rescaling

Tags: resize, javafx, label

Consider the following: a `BorderPane` with a `VBox` in the center and a `ListView` on the left. The `ListView` has a fixed (preferred) width. In the center `VBox` there are a bunch of `Label`s with text. I've chosen for this UI because I want the `Label`s to resize with the `Stage` (or thus `Scene`), so I placed them in the center of a  `BorderPane`. However, this allows the children to take up their preferred size, which for a `Label` means it grows with its `textProperty`. This implies the `Label`s grow too much and extend over the left part of the `BorderPane`. Adding the left part after the center part (first `setCenter` then `setLeft`) or the other way around doesn't make a difference.

What I want is that the `Label`s automatically scale with the `Stage` but upon becoming too small for the text to be on one line, wrap the text (for which I use `setTextWrap(true)`). However, it seems I need to set the `Label`s max with, but that would prevent them from resizing with the `Stage`. How can I best fix this?